# Jquery with HttpPost in MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my *.aspx page

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 418,
            width: 402,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $('form').submit();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

This calls not only the Controller's `Actionresult`, but it calls a separate controller's `ActionResult` that is also found in the form. I don't want all the `ActionResults` found in the page to be invoked.

Q: How can I get my confirm button, found in the View for `Members`, to only call

```
//found in MemberController.cs
// POST: /Member/Create
 [Authorize]
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(...){}
```

Comment: show your dialog html, your jquery selector `$('form')` submit all forms, you should use id or class or wrapping `div`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit only form that is inside dialog you could write like this, i think:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 418,
            width: 402,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    //notice this part
                    $('#dialog-confirm form').submit();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```